TabControl in avalonia not working as expected
Following is the MainWindowViewModel.cs code :
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using Neuroflow.Views;
using Neuroflow.Views.VisualizationViews;
using Avalonia.Controls;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Neuroflow.Services;

namespace Neuroflow.ViewModels;

public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [ObservableProperty] private TabItem? _currentOpenedView;

    [ObservableProperty] private ObservableCollection<TabItem> _openedViews;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        OpenedViews = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>
        {
            new TabItem("Visualization", new Visualization()),
            new TabItem("Linear Regression", new LinearRegression()),
            new TabItem("Logistic Regression", new LogisticRegression())
        };
       
    }
}

public partial class TabItem : ViewModelBase
{
    [ObservableProperty] private string _header;
    [ObservableProperty] private UserControl _content;

    public TabItem(string title, UserControl view)
    {
        Header = title;
        Content = view ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(view));
    }
}

MainWindow.axaml :
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:Neuroflow.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Neuroflow.Views;assembly=Neuroflow"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        xmlns:local="using:Neuroflow.Views"
        x:Class="Neuroflow.Views.MainWindow"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="Neuroflow"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        RequestedThemeVariant="Light">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Design.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Design.DataContext>


    

        <TabControl Name="InnerContent" ItemsSource="{Binding OpenedViews}" >

            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Header}" FontSize="12" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding   CurrentOpenedView.Content}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

        </TabControl>

    </DockPanel>
</Window>

The code is properly rendering the Title, however doesn't render the Content properly ( works fine when i hard code everything ), so the problem seems to be arising from the template code.I also tried the following ( doesn't work either )
<TabControl x:Name="TabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding OpenedViews}"></TabControl>
Also tried the following :
<ContentControl Content="{Binding   CurrentOpenedView.Content}" />
Replacing CurrentOpenedView.Content with Content doesn't work ( Intellisence gives red lines before hand )
The error i get is :
0>MainWindow.axaml(68,37): Error AVLN2000 Avalonia: Unable to resolve property or method of name 'CurrentOpenedView' on type 'XamlX.TypeSystem.XamlPseudoType'. Line 68, position 37.

0>------- Finished building project: Neuroflow. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 4


I wouldn't use ContentPresenter outside of control template. You have data template, please use ContentControl.

The DataContext of an Template is the object being templated itself. In the same way your {Binding Header} is binding to TabItem.Header, the binding {Binding   CurrentOpenedView.Content} is attempting to bind to TabItem.CurrentOpenedView.Content, which doesn't exist because that property is in your ViewModel, not the TabItem.
Since each item has it's own templated TabItem, you should be able to just bind the Content directly with {Binding Content}

Your ViewModels should not know anything about the Views, your view models should be look like this
namespace Neuroflow.ViewModels;

using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [ObservableProperty] private TabItemViewModelBase? _currentOpenedView;

    [ObservableProperty] private ObservableCollection<TabItemViewModelBase> _openedViews;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        OpenedViews = [
            new VisualizationViewModel(),
            new LinearRegressionViewModel(),
            new LogisticRegressionViewModel(),
            ];
    }
}


public abstract class TabItemViewModelBase : ViewModelBase
{
    public abstract string Header { get; }
}

public partial class VisualizationViewModel : TabItemViewModelBase
{
    public override string Header => "Visualization";
}

public partial class LinearRegressionViewModel : TabItemViewModelBase
{
    public override string Header => "Linear Regression";
}

public partial class LogisticRegressionViewModel : TabItemViewModelBase
{
    public override string Header => "Logistic Regression";
}

per each ViewModel, you have a corosponding userControl in the Views Namespace
MainWindow.axaml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="Neuroflow.Views.MainWindow" 
        xmlns:vm ="using:Neuroflow.ViewModels"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        xmlns:local ="using:Neuroflow.Views"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >

  <DockPanel>
    <TabControl Name="InnerContent" ItemsSource="{Binding OpenedViews}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentOpenedView}">
      <TabControl.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
          <TabItem Header="{Binding Header}" Content="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>         
      </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>

LinearRegressionView.axaml
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="Neuroflow.Views.LinearRegressionView">
  Linear Regression View
</UserControl>

VisualizationView.axaml
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="Neuroflow.Views.VisualizationView">
  Visualization View 
</UserControl>

LogisticRegressionView.axaml
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="Neuroflow.Views.LogisticRegressionView">
  Logistic Regression View
</UserControl>

this will automagically will work due to View locator which rely on the naming convention

make sure that all views in Neuroflow.Views Namespace and the name end with View
make sure that all View Models in Neuroflow.ViewModels namespace end with ViewModel
each view model has a corresponding view with same name (with different ending of course)

